# Как реализовать сужающийся border на css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как можно реализовать такой border на css, чтобы он шел снизу вверх и сужался, а где-то на середине заканчивался?
Вот дизайн: 
[image: это дизайн сайта]

Comment: Попробуйте так:     box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px #ff5656;

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  position: relative;
}
div:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
}
div:hover:before, div:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}
div:before {
  border: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #f00;
  left: -3px;
}
div:after {
  border: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid #f00;
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, pink);
  padding: 2px;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.outer div {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.outer div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="outer">
    <img src="https://www.e-news.pro/uploads/posts/2018-05/1525395939_e-news.su_43346481_from_me_to_you_00000000.jpg" alt="">
    <div>
      <span>Beatles</span>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 30" width="100">
      <path d="M0,15 15,0 30,15 45,0 60,15 75,0 90,15" fill="none" stroke="pink" stroke-width="4"/>
    </svg>
      <span> 4000.26 Р-р</span>

      <a href="#">Смотреть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```